# What for do we use the `terminal-output` tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've just stumbled around on TeX.SX and found some questions tagged with `terminal-output`. This tag has no description. Currently it is used for some questions just because they include error messages from the terminal and for some questions really dealing with terminal output (e.g. via `\typeout`).

What is that tag really for?

Comment: You can provide a description yourself. I think it is rather meant for making LaTeX look like a terminal emulation, i.e. show content in LaTeX like if it has been a snapshot of a terminal window.